# Iterate Through Nested JavaScript Objects - Dirty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have some JavaScript that I wrote in a pinch, but I think it could be optimized greatly by someone smarter than me. This code runs on relatively small objects, but it runs a fair amount of times, so its worth getting right:

```
/**
 *  Determine the maximum quantity we can show (ever) for these size/color combos
 *
 *  @return int=settings.limitedStockThreshold
 */
function getMaxDefaultQuantity() {
    var max_default_quantity = 1;

    if (inventory && inventory.sizes) {
        sizecolor_combo_loop:
        for (var key in inventory.sizes) {
            if (inventory.sizes[key].combos) {
                for (var key2 in inventory.sizes[key].combos) {
                    var sizecolor_combo = inventory.sizes[key].combos[key2];
                    if (isBackorderable(sizecolor_combo)) {
                    //if even one is backorderable, we can break out
                        max_default_quantity = settings.limitedStockThreshold;
                        break sizecolor_combo_loop;
                    } else {
                    //not backorderable, get largest quantity (sizecolor_combo or max_default_quantity)
                        var qoh = parseInt(sizecolor_combo.quantityOnHand || 1);
                        if (qoh > max_default_quantity) {
                            max_default_quantity = qoh;
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };

    return Math.min(max_default_quantity, settings.limitedStockThreshold);
};
```

First, **inventory** is a object returned via JSON. It has a property **inventory.sizes** that contain all of the available sizes for a product. Each size has a property **inventory.sizes.combos** which maps to all of the available colors for a size. Each combo also has a property **quantityOnHand** that tells the quantity available for that specific combo. (the JSON structure returned cannot be modified)

What the code does is loop through each size, then each size's combos. It then checks if the size-color combo is backorderable (via another method). If it any combo is backorderable, we can stop because the default quantity is defined elsewhere. If the combo isn't backorderable, the max_default_quantity is the largest quantityOnHand we find (with a maximum of settings.limitedStockThreshold).

I really don't like the nested for loops and my handling of the math and default values feels overly complicated.

Also, this whole function is wrapped in a much larger jQuery object if that helps clean it up.

Comment: FYI, you don't need semi-colons at the end of JavaScript code blocks.

Comment: @Jacob I'd dare say! If I wrote that *there wouldn't be a single semi-colon* cluttering the code!

Comment: I add semicolons because the code seems to compress better using JS-Minifier. Its a recent habit I've picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have much in the way of elegant collection processing capabilities if you have to support older browsers, so without the help of additional libraries, a nested loop like the one you've written is the way to go.  You could consider having the values precomputed server-side instead, perhaps cached, and including it in the JSON to avoid having to run the same computations again and again.

Comment: @Jacob, never heard of the newer Array iteration methods (map, reduce, filter, each...)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods Sure, IE 8 may not support them, but it's incorrect to say that JS doesn't have much in the way of ellegant collection processing capabilities

Comment: Edited answer to specify that it only applies to older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using map-reduce? See a [live](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/qPRNF/11/) example of a functional approach.

This particular example uses [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) so we can keep it on a elegant level without having to implement the details.

```
function doStuff(inventory) {
    var max = settings.limitedStockThreshold;
    if (!(inventory && inventory.sizes)) return;

    var quantity = _(inventory.sizes).chain()
        .filter(function(value) {
            return value.combos;
        })
        .map(function(value) {
            return _(value.combos).chain()
                .map(function(value) {
                    return isBackorderable(value) ? max : value.quantityOnHand;
                })
                .max().value();
        })
        .max().value();

    return Math.min(quantity, max);
}
```

As for an explanation:

We take the inventory.sizes set and remove any that don't contain combos. We then map each size to the maximum quantity of it's colour. We do this mapping each combo to either its quantity or the maximum quantity if backordable. We then take a max of that set.

Finally we take a max of set of maxQuantities per size.

We're still effectily doing a double for loop since we take two `.max` on the set but it doesn't look as dirty.

There are also a couple of if checks that you had in place that are still there.

[Edit]

I'm pretty sure the above code can be optimized a lot more. but it's a different way of looking at it.

Comment: This code is certainly elegant. Is there any way to refactor this without relying on the underscore library? Maybe just using jQuery.map() instead? I'm trying to avoid adding an additional library for a single task.

Comment: You can define all these functions yourself. map, filter & max aren't that hard to define. Look at the underscore source. I only used it because hides the annoying cross-browser details. If your restricted to a decent browser then `array.reduce`, `array.map`, `array.filter` are all native. If your going to write functional code do it throughout the project not just one function. underscore is a lightweight utility belt to make doing just that easy.